# $4^x-4^{x-1}=24$ what is the value of $(2x)^x$?"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So, every week our teacher gives us a very difficult question worth 1 point and I can never get them right, so I would highly appreciate the person who tells and explains, in good detail, why this problem solves the way it does and each step you took to find the answer. When you answer I would also greatly appreciate your taking into account my age of 16, because of this i may not comprehend some words so if u could take a bit more effort to explain your meanings, that would be fantastic. Just so you know, the class i'm in is Advanced Algebra II.

Now for the question; $4^x-4^{x-1}=24$ what is the value of $(2x)^x$?"

Comment: You write fancy by placing maths stuff between $ signs and using functions from http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/

Comment: I'd suggest retitling your question for clarity.

Comment: Do you already know what a logarithm is?

Comment: 1)sorry for the bad grammar

Comment: 2)sorry, im a newb, im getting better at using the website though.

Comment: 3) I have no idea what a logarithm is

Comment: Are you supposed to have an idea about it?

Comment: im am not, perhaps the faintest idea, but that's it.

Comment: I'm new to the website and i think it is very cool that you actually use programming code, of sorts, to post.

Comment: You could simplify the equation to $4^x\cdot (1-4^{-1})=24$ and then to $4^x=32$. Using $4=2^2$, you should be able to guess $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4^x - 4^{x-1}=24$$
$$(2^x)^2 - \dfrac{1}{4}4^x=24$$
$$2^{2x} - \dfrac{1}{4}2^{2x}=24$$
$$4\cdot 2^{2x} - 2^{2x} = 96$$
$$4\cdot 2^{2x} - 2^{2x} - 96 = 0$$
Let $a=2^{2x}$. Then:
$$4\cdot 2^{2x} - 2{2x} - 96$$
$$=4a - a - 96 = 0$$
$$3a - 96 = 0$$
$$3a = 96$$
$$a = \dfrac{96}{3}$$
$$a = 32$$
Replace $a$ with $2^{2x}$ again.
$$2^{2x} = 32$$
Equate the exponents and solve for $x$. Remember that if you have an equation $x^m = x^n$, then it logically follows that $m = n$. Note that this is not an "if and only if" statement. Special cases like $0^2=0^3$ will pop up.
$$2^{2x} = 2^5$$
$$2x = 5$$
$$x = \dfrac{5}{2}$$
Finding $(2x)^x$ is easy; just plug in the value of x.
$$\left[2\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\right]^{5/2}$$
$$=5^{5/2}$$
$$=\sqrt[2]{5^5}$$
$$=\sqrt[2]{5^4}\cdot\sqrt[2]{5^1}$$
$$=5^2\cdot\sqrt{5}$$
$$=25\sqrt{5}$$
**Final Answer:**
When $4^x - 4^{x-1} = 24$, then $x = \dfrac{5}{2}$. So, $(2x)^x = 25\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Careful, the original question used the difference of $4^x$ and $4^{x-1}$, not the sum.

Comment: I fixed the problem

Comment: Thank you! i couldn't get it but now i do, thanks again.

Comment: @user128689 Don't thank me by posting in the comments, but by accepting answers. Read the **Pay it forward** section at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer :)

Comment: $(-1)^2 = (-1)^4 $ but $2\neq 4$.

Comment: @RR Whoops did not notice that thanks

Answer (score 8):

Hint: There's a term that you can factor from the left-hand side of your equation. What is it? What do you get if you rewrite that side as the product of two terms?

Beyond that, as I'm sure you know, $4 = 2^2$ and $8 = 2^3$.  Just sayin'.

Comment: The reason i'm asking is because I've missed 1 1/2 weeks of school so i need some help. these answers are a bit to vague to help me, could i have a bit more of an explanation?

Comment: @user128689: Okay, but keep in mind that you probably learned to factor more than two weeks ago :). Remember, $4^x$ and $4^{x-1}$ are *numbers*. For example, the first one is $4$ multiplied by itself $x$ times. That statement tells you that $4^x$ is the product of other numbers. Which is smaller: $4^x$ and $4^{x-1}$? Will the smaller number divide into the larger?

Comment: ooooooh, now I'm seeing where this is headed, thanks very much =D

Comment: @user128689: Let us know what answer you get. (By the way, technically, logarithms do come up, but if you haven't studied them yet, you probably won't even notice where. That won't stop you from finding the solution.)

Comment: Alright, i will post when i get the Correct answer, but don't hold your breath. =D

Answer (score 3):

Let us start with your equation which is $$4^x - 4^{x-1}=24$$ First, factor $4^x$; this gives $$ 4^x \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{3\ 4^x}{4}=24$$ So $4^x=32$ which can write $2^{2x}=2^5$. So $2x=5$ and then $x=\frac{5}{2}$. So now, we know the value of $x$.

We can now compute the value of  $(2x)^x$ which is, since  $x=\frac{5}{2}$, the value of $5^{\frac{5}{2}}$ that is to say $5^{2+\frac{1}{2}}=5^2 5^{\frac{1}{2}}=25 \sqrt{5}$